# progress bar in asp.net web application using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to make a progress bar that fills up every time a user goes from page to page..I've made an online survey and I want after each question displayed on a page the progress bar to be fill.Let's say I have 10 questions.After the user answers 3 the progress bar will be fill with 3/10 and so on. How can I make such a progress bar?

Comment: you can assign the number of answers answered to the value of the progress bar right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [progress bar on a survey using c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9080470/progress-bar-on-a-survey-using-c-sharp)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this should do the job:

```
<div id="progressBar" style="width:500px;border:solid 1px blue;">
    <div style="background-color:blue;width:<%=percentageComplete%>%"></div>
</div>
```

Where percentageComplete is set in you page/usercontrol.

Comment: But what to assign to that percentageComplete?

Comment: In your example where you are 3/10 through, you would apply a value of 30.

Comment: <div id="progressBar" style="width:500px;border:solid 1px blue;">
    <div style="background-color:blue;width:30%"></div>
</div>

Comment: yeah..this I understand but how to set the percentageComplete value? depending on what?

Comment: Do you have a question per page? If so then I'd just have a constant defined at the top of each code behind file that is the hardcoded value for that page. So the first would be 0, second would be 10 etc. If you don't have a question per page you'd need to use javascript.