# progress bar on a survey using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I made an on-line survey in asp.net using c#. My survey contains 30 questions each question on a different page.I want to display a progress bar that will show the user how much he completed. How can I do that?

Comment: Something like this, maybe?  http://www.ajaxprojects.com/ajax/tutorialdetails.php?itemid=307

Comment: I didn't try anything because I don't have any idea of how to start.I was hoping someone will lead me in a direction...

Comment: Ah, just realised the download link was dead - thought it was a tutorial.  Doh!

Comment: its really hard to answer with out knowing your data model, if you are using web forms/mvc and what your expected output is.

Comment: I answered it here- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9082155/progress-bar-in-asp-net/9082337#9082337

Answer (score 2):

You could use individual images or you could use a small bit of CSS to calculate this:

We'll suppose we know what page we're on and it's stored in a variable somewhere in our code.

Given that, we can do a quick percentage calculation of the current progress:

If we're on page 3:

```
3/30 * 100 = 10
```

With this stored in a variable we can use it to set the width of our progres bar, relative to its parent:

```
#myProgressBar{
  width: 10%;
}
```

(You'd be writing the value to the CSS statement using your language of choice, C# in this case).

Here's a quick sample of how it might look:

http://jsfiddle.net/QnbdZ/1/

Comment: So you put this css in every page statical? :P

Comment: For your survey you can just drop it into the top of your Master Page. Simples.

Comment: and how will it know on what page the user will be?

Comment: You said that your survey is split over 30 pages. How do you currently know which page they're on? i.e. How do you currently know which question to ask them?

Comment: I'm taking my questions from a database..

Comment: Yeah of course. So how do you know which question you're upto? How do you know which one to show next?

Comment: By the questions id..I know that the question with the id 1 is on page 3

Comment: So you do have a way to know which page you're on? That's good. Use that number.

Answer (score -1):

There is most easy way for this is to have 30 Images with representing progress over there and then use each one on the top or bottom of the page to show the progress.