# progress bar in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [progress bar on a survey using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9080470/progress-bar-on-a-survey-using-c-sharp)

I made an on-line survey in ASP .NET using C#. My survey contains 30 questions with each question on a different page. I want to display a progress bar that will show the user how much he completed. How can I do that?

I think that if I know the total number of pages, on each page when I hit the submit button the progress bar will fill according to the page the user is on. For example, if i am on the 5th page out of 30 then the progress bar should fill with 5 / 30 or something like this.

Comment: You have the right idea. What are you really stuck on? Did you try writing any code for this? Is each question its own .ASPX file?

Comment: Yes..each question is on a aspx page

Comment: @Bibu - please do not repost your question.

Comment: it's the same question but with another ideea...

Comment: what do you mean a different idea? you should edit your previous question.

Answer (score 1):

If you pages are always in the same order, then you know which page in the sequence your on. if not same order , then you'll have to use session to save the page, or maybe a hidden field that gets posted back, what the last page count was.

-Design wise, you could do 30 different images, not the best solution.

-using one sliding image, using the css background positioning, every page it would slide over a certain percentage, until it gets to the other side of the container, which is 100%.

-Or using css, have a div inside another div, the outer div will have the full width and a border, then inner would grow a certain percentage each page. You give the inner a different background color.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way would be to simply store number of completed pages or current page number in the session and on the load of the next page, use the stored value to setup the progress bar.

Comment: and how would I retain the page that is completed?

Comment: @Bibu: you just increment the number you get from your session variable - then store it in the same place for the next page.

Answer (score 0):

I use this simple jquery script, I have an progress bar image which is just empty progress bar and then I have another image to fillup the progress bar. I adjust the width of the div which contains filled part (progressBarFill div its background image is solid color image with width 1 pixel). On each page you just have to change the step number,

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var progressBarWidth = 211;         // this is total width of the progress bar
        var totalStepsInAppProcess = 5;     // number of steps in an application process
        var eachStepPercent = 100 / 5;      // each steps percentage
        var numberOfSubStepsForStep = 1;    // if there are any sub steps in the step - if no sub steps then it should be 1 to avoid divide by zero error
        var stepNumber = 3;                 // step number  
        var percentForSubStep = Math.ceil(new Number(eachStepPercent / numberOfSubStepsForStep).toFixed(2)) * stepNumber; // equivalent percentage for a step
        var subStepNumber = 1;              // sub step number - if no sub steps then it should be 1 to avoid math errors
        var widthForThisStep = Math.ceil((progressBarWidth * (percentForSubStep / 100)) * subStepNumber);  // progress bar width for this step
        var label = (document.getElementById('<%=((Label)Master.FindControl("lb_ProgressBarText")).ClientID %>'));
        $('#<%=((Label)Master.FindControl("lb_ProgressBarText")).ClientID %>').text('You are ' + percentForSubStep + '% done');
        $('.progressBarFill').width(widthForThisStep);
    </script>
```

I hope this helps.